# PhantomJS console charset

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, web-crawler, phantomjs

I'm trying to run below code but my console prints weird charset.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "http://www.bdtong.co.kr/index.php?c_category=C02"
//var url = "http://www.baemin.com/";
/*
var option = {
    encoding : "euc-kr"
}
*/
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, line, source) {
    //phantom.outputEncoding = "utf8";
    console.log('console> '+msg);
};

page.open(url, function() {

    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
          console.log('시작');
          $('.listMain > li').each(function () {
            //console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
            console.log($(this).find('p').text());
          });
        }, function(){
            phantom.exit();
        });
    });

});
```

All options have failed. (For example phantomjs's option, phantom.outputEncoding, window cmd's chcp setting, even window file encoding)

[cf. captured console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lHg9.png) .

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a cause. This problem was simply the MS console encoding issues. I just typed 'chcp' command and console show me a clear screen. That's all.